# Composer: How to skip specific files of a package while instllation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I created my own Composer package with a small library (A single `.php` file.) for CodeIgniter. The code is hosted on GitHub and the package is available via Packagist.

I have a CodeIgniter project and use Composer to put the library into the `libraries` directory of CodeIgniter. This works fine. But I have the following problems:

- The `.gitignore`, `LICENSE`, `README.md` and `composer.json` of the package will be put into the directory. I do only want the single `.php` file in it.
- Also a `vendor` directory will be created, but I do not need it.

Is it possible to configure the `composer.json` to skip / ignore this files and directories?

It could also be possible, that I misunderstood how Composer works or that it is the wrong tool for this. An alternative approach would be nice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used the [hooks mechanism](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to perform this task. Many packages came with documentation or test folders we did not want to package ourselves.

Simply create a class with a static method and register it as `pre-package-install` and `post-package-install`.

Composer comes with a small but efficient [utility class](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Util/Filesystem.html) that is very useful when cleaning-up the vendor folder.